# How to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{4})}{\Gamma(n+\frac{5}{4})}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

How can I prove that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{4})}{\Gamma(n+\frac{5}{4})}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

The closest I've gotten is that if I call the sum S, then using the definition of the Beta function:
$$\sqrt{\pi}S=\intop_0^1\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x}}dx$$
But I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: Computed by Mathematica, for general parameters: $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-x)^n \Gamma (n+a)}{\Gamma (n+b)}=\frac{\Gamma (a) \, _2F_1(1,a;b;-x)}{\Gamma (b)}$$ where: $\, _2F_1(1,a;b;-1)$ is the hypergeometric function.

Comment: [Similar sum/integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505569/show-sum-limits-k-0-infty-1k-frac-gamma-leftk-frac14-right-gamma); see the further linked questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we substitute $x=u^4$ to obtain
$$\int_0^1{x^{-1/4}\over(1+x)\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx
=4\int_0^1{u^2\over(1+u^4)\sqrt{1-u^4}}\,du.$$
Then we substitute $u=1/v$ to get

$$4\int_1^\infty{v^2\over(1+v^4)\sqrt{v^4-1}}\,dv.$$

Then substitute $v=\sqrt{\tan y}$:

$$\begin{align*}
4\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\tan y\over(1+\tan^2y)\sqrt{\tan^2y-1}}
{\sec^2y\over2\sqrt{\tan y}}\,dy
&=2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\sqrt{\tan y}\over\sqrt{\tan^2y-1}}\,dy \\
&=2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\sqrt{\sin y\cos y}\over\sqrt{\sin^2y-\cos^2y}}\,dy\\
&=\sqrt2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\sqrt{\sin(2y)}\over\sqrt{-\cos(2y)}}\,dy\\
&=\sqrt2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{-\tan(2y)}\,dy.
\end{align*}$$
Now we substitute $w=-2y$ to get
$${\sqrt2\over2}\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi/2}\sqrt{\tan w}\,dw
={1\over\sqrt2}{\pi\over\sqrt2}
={\pi\over2}$$
as needed. (The integral $\int\sqrt{\tan x}\,dx$ is standard; see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/828640/).)